# How does this for loop condition work?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, eloquent

The code example below is from Eloquent Javascript Chapter 4 Exercise 4.3 (A List).

Why does the for-loop in the code below stop with the middle condition in the 
for-loop being "node"?

```
function listToArray(list) {
  array = [];
  for (var node=list; node; node = node.rest)
    array.push(node.value);
  return array;
}

list = { value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } } };
console.log(listToArray(list));
```

Comment: It'll stop when node is null as this will return a falsey value which causes the loop to terminate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we can write the program in a different way it will be more understandable

```
function listToArray(list) {

  array = [];
  for (var i=list;i; i = i.rest)
  {
    array.push(i.value);
   alert(array)
  }
}

var listobject = { value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } } };

listToArray(listobject);
```

Here listobject  is an **[object literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/)** and using the for loop we are traverse through the values of the object literal , or properties of object literal.

We can take each line of the code

1)  `listToArray(listobject);`

this is the function call, here we are passing object as an argument to the function.

2)When this code executes then  the control goes to the function definition

```
 function listToArray(list) { ...}
```

Here the **list** is the same argument what we are passing at the time of function call.

3) `array = [];`
inside the function we are declaring an array, initially the array has no elements.

4)next is our for loop.   `for (var i=list;list; i = i.rest)`

inside loop first we assigning var i=list;

means we are assign all the property of the object list to i

That means we can access every property of object via `i`,

example:

> i.value will result 10

5) next  Condition statement here it is `i` and in your program it is node

all have same meaning in this case :

the condition will false when  `i` is null, in your case `node` is null.

6)`i=i.rest`

it will give the property of the object or value of the object.

Example : `listobject.value will result 10`

```
listobject.rest.value will result 20

listobject.rest.rest.value will result 30
```

7) and finally `array.push(i.value);`

add the values to our array and in this our array contains 10,20,30

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I am wondering how the .rest method works? Does it provide the ability to listobject.value to work? So it then also allows listobject.rest to work as well? Is there documentation on this?

Comment: @EricPark when you assign var i=list then all property of the list object is assigned to i then we can use i.object peroperty

Answer (score 1):

I had your same question: it was not clear to me, and I hoped that for a learning JavaScript book it would have been explained better. Then I stopped and thinking, and went with the following consideration.

The author's "fault", IMHO, lies in a simple thing: instead of simply write `node` as the second statement he could have written `node != null`, that would have been much more prominent and teaching-friendly ("do the loop while node is not null": and since `node` is null only in the last iteration - then returning `false` - it will stop there): try yourself, this works

Answer (score 0):

You can use for..of loop better: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of